# Where do I select the module to run @Tagged JUnit 5 tests for?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

When setting up a run configuration for tests that are tagged with `@Tag("unit")`, IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 says there is no module specified. After looking around for a while and searching the docs, I can't seem to find where/how to set the module. Please advise.

#### Update

This appears to be a bug and is reported at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202889

[image]

Comment: What exact IDE version do you use? "Use classpath of module" field should be active.

Comment: @y.bedrov IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-128.5107.16 built on November 6, 2018 for macOS. Is your field active?

Comment: I use the Windows version (Community 2018.2 Nov. 6 2018) and am able to run JUnit5 tagged test with IntelliJ just fine. I see that in your image `Use classpath or module:` is not active but that is where it is set in mine. Are you saying that you can not change that field?

Comment: @GuyCoder No, it's disabled.

Comment: When I create the test I run the test as regular, not as a tag. Then after the test run I change the type to tag, which should leave the module field the same and fill in the tag field.

Comment: @GuyCoder That would have been a great workaround and looked promising for a while - until I switched to "Tag", which reset the field to <no module> and disabled it. Must be a bug. Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: @DoubleM Hope the answer is found or it is determined to be a bug and is fixed sooner rather than later.

Comment: @GuyCoder Sadly, still present in 2018.3

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to [have been fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202869/Run-Configuration-with-Test-Kind-TAGS-has-unsolvable-Error).

Here is a screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA Community 2023.2.1:

[image]